# Apache Kafka 0.9.0.0 Show all Topics with Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm currently evaluating Apache Kafka and I have a simple consumer that is supposed to read messages from a specific topic partition. Here is my client:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

    TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition("test_topic", Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

    ArrayList topicAssignment = new ArrayList();
    topicAssignment.add(partition0);
    consumer.assign(topicAssignment);

    //consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic"));
    int commitInterval = 200;
    List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>();

    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            buffer.add(record);
            if (buffer.size() >= commitInterval) {
                process(buffer);
                consumer.commitSync();
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}

static void process(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffers) {
   for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> buffer : buffers) {
       System.out.println(buffer);
   }
}
```

Here is the command that I use to start Apache Kafka:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties & bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic test_topic
```

As you can see here, I'm creating the topic with 2 partitions (p0 and p1)!

I'm then starting two instances of my consumer with the following commands:

For Consumer 1:

```
java -cp target/scala-2.11/kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar com.test.api.consumer.KafkaConsumer09Java 0
```

For Consumer 2:

```
java -cp target/scala-2.11/kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar com.test.api.consumer.KafkaConsumer09Java 1
```

Where 0 and 1 represent the actual partition from which I want my consumer's to read the messages from.

But what happens is that only my Consumer 1 is getting all the messages. I was under the impression that the messages from the producer end up equally on the partitions.

I used the following command to see how many partitions that I have for my topic test_topic:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 joe$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --broker-info --group test --topic test_topic --zookeeper localhost:2181
[2016-01-14 13:36:48,831] WARN WARNING: ConsumerOffsetChecker is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0. Use ConsumerGroupCommand instead. (kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker$)
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
test            test_topic                     0   10000           10000           0               none
BROKER INFO
0 -> 172.22.4.34:9092
```

Why is there only one partition even though I said to Kafka to create 2 partitions for the test_topic?

Here is my producer:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("VPP metrics producer")
    //val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val props: Properties = new Properties()
      props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093")
      props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")

    val config = new ProducerConfig(props)
    val producer = new Producer[String, String](config)

    1 to 10000 map {
      case i => 
        val jsonStr = getRandomTsDataPoint().toJson.toString
        println(s"sending message $i to kafka")
        producer.send(new KeyedMessage[String, String]("test_topic", jsonStr))
        println(s"sent message $i to kafka")
    }
  }
```

Comment: quite interesting! I also wanted to check this with no success. I've seen some more detailed output when there is an ownership for each partition but didnt know how to assign ownership...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would have 1 partition if you created the topic with 2. Never happened to me, that's for sure.

Can you try this:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test_topic`

That should show you how many partitions are really there.

Then, if there's really 1 partition, maybe you could start over by creating a new topic with:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic test_topic_2`

And then try:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test_topic_2`

... and report back the findings.

Comment: Joes-MacBook-Pro:kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 joe$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test_topic_2
Joes-MacBook-Pro:kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 joe$

Comment: Sorry I missed your questions. This won't work for Kafka 0.9, since it no longer stores consumer offset information in ZK, but in a special Kafka topic instead. I use Kafka Monitor to monitor my consumer offsets, so maybe you can check it out (works for 0.9). [Especially elegant if you're using Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpodeszwik/kafka-offset-monitor): `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e ZK=<zookeeper_location> jpodeszwik/kafka-offset-monitor:0.2.1`. If not, go to the [github repo](https://github.com/jpodeszwik/docker-kafka-offset-monitor) to see how to run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are just consuming from partition 0 but you also need to consume from partition 1. If you consume from 1 and commit you will see in column pid no also no 1.

But you also need a producer which writes into 1 also.

Comment: Isn't Kafka supposed to do that automatically by writing the messages in a round robin fashion to the partitions? I have edited my post to include the producer. How and what should I make such that it writes to the partitions?

Comment: Additionally, my consumer 2 is reading from partition 1. Take a look at the last parameter in my post above! "For Consumer 2:"

Comment: @sparkr i missed that one with consumer 2. Sorry for that. I was experimenting with kafka today also. what I experienced was that while stuffing into kafka and in parallel letting consumer 2 consume only it worked for me. I dont understand exactly when the partition switches. I'm working with the python api. Default from producer should be that it serves to the two partitions... and in fact it does in my case... there is a setting called random_start=True //should be default.

Comment: What is the solution for this? I mean there seems to be so much hype about Apache Kafka and if I have to struggle to get the basic stuff working, I'm not so convinced!

Comment: I want to write to two partitions and read from these two partitions using a consumer and I expect consumer 1 to read 50% of the messages and consumer 2 the remaining 50% of the messages. What should I do in my code above to achieve this?