# Apache Kafka list all Topics

Tags: apache-kafka

Is this any bug with the Apache Kafka 0.9.0.0? I'm using the following command to list the topics and I get nothing even though the server was started with a topic being created!

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 joe$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
Joes-MacBook-Pro:kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 joe$
```

Here is the command that I used to start Apache Kafka:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties & bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test_topic
```

It is getting harsh for me to just try out the basic stuff around the much hyped Apache Kafka. Here is one another example where I'm pretty much stuck!

[Apache Kafka 0.9.0.0 Show all Topics with Partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789999/apache-kafka-0-9-0-0-show-all-topics-with-partitions/34799001?noredirect=1#comment57344740_34799001)

Comment: Kafka 0.9 was recently released and may contain bugs. We are successfully running 0.8.2 in production. Is that an option you can consider?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see the zookeeper started in your code.
Please start zookeeper and then kafka in the same order.

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
```

Try to list the topics with the below command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

You can create the topic with the below command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Once the topic is created, you get a message saying "test" created.
Now you can try list command to see your topic listed.

Note: The replication factor depends upon the number of brokers that you run on a single server.